# Getting data from TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 files:
**database.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    class DatabaseService{
      final String uid;
      DatabaseService({required this.uid});
      final CollectionReference userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    
      Future updateUserData(String name) async {
        return await userCollection.doc(uid).set({
          'name': name,
        });
      }
```

another file called **auth.dart**

```dart
class AuthService{
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
        try{
          UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
          User? user = result.user;
    
          // Create a new document for the user with the uid
          await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid).updateUserData();
          return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
        }
        catch(e){
          print(e);
          return null;
        }
      }
}
```

And another file called **register.dart** with this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  String name = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration
                  (
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                    hintText: "Full Name",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))
                ),
                validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                onChanged: (val){
                  setState(() => name = val);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );

  }
}
```

I want to get the data from TextFormField on **register.dart** to pass into the function `updateUserData` on **auth.dart**. This means the Name will be the data from the keyboard input by the user.
How can I do it? Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I can see you are already getting the values in the name variable. Trying printing it on onchanged.

Comment: I need to call that name variable on the file auth.dart inside the updateUserData(). How can I do it?

Comment: use Function callback

Comment: @p2kr it also doesn't work tho

Comment: @p2kr did you mean TextEditingController?

Comment: yes that TextEditingController. Sorry for typo

Comment: I tried to use TextEditingController but I don't know how to call it in auth.dart file because it just a class ClassName(){ } without stateless or staful. I just updated the auth.dart file

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are using a Form in combination to TextFormField, in order to retrieve your value you can set a Key to your Form and use it to retrieve your data.

In the case of a simple TextField, you would assign a TextEditingController to it and retrieve its value that way.

Here is an example with a Form, a Key, and validators:

You can then use this value to call your auth fonction with the name as parameter.

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (newValue) {
                setState(() => name = newValue);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState!.save(); // Calls onSaved method in your fields
                  // Other actions such as call your update method
                }
              },
              child: Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: But the problem is how can I call the value from TextFormField from class AuthService on auth.dart file?

Comment: You have to expose your DatabaseService via a provider for example to make it available throughout your app and call 
```DatabaseService dbs = DatabaseService();
dbs.updateUsername(value)```

Comment: I would recommend the package Getx if you are a beginner it is super easy to understand and use.